# Identify whether Contour is symmetrical OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have computed contours from binary image in OpenCV with respective bounding rotated rectangles as well as minimum ellipses in order to get to know the shape of the contours. However, i would like to know that if the shape is symmetrical even on one axis.

So, is it possible to compute whether the contour is symmetrical?? 
(while not necessarily 100% symmetrical)

The sample contour is as below:

[image: Sample Contour] [image] [image]

Comment: your question is not very clear and you didn't provide anything you tried... Do you consider the image in your example as symmetrical?

Comment: which symmetry axis would there be in your sample image? if you only consider the principal component axes this task should be easy to solve.

Comment: @ChrisMaes, Sorry for not being clear with question, but the main objective for me is to identify whether the contour is irregular in shape or not, i have tried others way such as the distance between center of mass and centroid, ratio of contour area to the minimum ellipses, point in polygon among others. For your clarification, i would say the contour in the image as maybe 80% symmetrical in both axis. Thanks

Comment: that's more of a research project, not just a small coding question...

Comment: symmetrical along vertical, horizontal only, or along any axis?

Comment: @Micka, I dont really care about which symmetry axis as long as i can decide from the contours whether it is regular or irregular in shape. Sorry but can i know what do you meant by principal component axes?? Thanks

Comment: @ChrisMaes, ya, i agreed that it is more of a research project, but i wouldn't want a full fledged symmetry detection but just approximation of it. Thus, wondering whether there might be any hacks in regards of this problem. Regarding axes, i didnt really care any about axes. Thanks a lot

Comment: principal component axes can be found by PCA and should be identical to your RotatedRect axes. If you instead consider "any" axes, how would you expect to test for symmetry?!?

Comment: have a look at " J. Flusser and T. Suk, "Rotation Moment Invariants for Recognition of Symmetric Objects", IEEE Trans. Image Proc., vol. 15, pp. 3784–3790, 2006. "

Comment: @Micka, thanks for reply, let say if the scope is just narrowed down to principal component axes as in the rotated rects, would it be possible to compute it??

Comment: @Micka, thanks a lot for the resource, i will take a serious look at it

Comment: I would just rotate/mirror each (or each n-th) contour pixel around the axis and test the distance to the nearest contour point (with a precomputed distance transform). define a threshold to count inlier and outlier and at the end define a ratio how many inlier there must be or sth to count a contour as "nearly symmetric" around that axis.

Comment: Post a few images with the contour only

Comment: @Micka, Thanks a lot for your suggestion, i have been experimenting with solution almost like yours too but yours seems better, will try it later

Comment: @Miki, will post few more images, thanks.